# How to pass prop to component from array of components in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Let's say you have an array of components:

```
var my_array = [ <SomeComponent1 textcolor={defaultFontColor} />, <MyComponent2 textcolor={defaultFontColor} />}, <SomeComponent3 textcolor={defaultFontColor} />}, ...]
```

And you wanted to iterate over the array, but also pass props to the component (in the example, `AComponent`):

```
my_array.map(AComponent => {
      return (
        <View>
          {AComponent}
        </View>
      )
})
```

How would I pass a prop to `{AComponent}` in this example?

Comment: How do you create the array of components to begin with? Wouldn't it be easier to pass all of the necessary props there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider component as a json object

```
AComponent = {
   props:{
    prop1: "value for the prop1"
  }
}
```

So, now you can pass the props you wish like

```
my_array.map(AComponent => {
  AComponent.props["newProp"] = "propValue"
  return (
    <View>
      {AComponent}
    </View>
  )
})
```

Or, if you wish to use the props passed while pushing the component in the array you can directly use them in the render() method of the component

Comment: When I try that I get the following error: "Component Exception: attempted to assign to readonly property"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7gnLv48u/

Try React.cloneElement to create a clone of your component and add additional props

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle, very helpful!